# Flutter Health plugin fetch workouts in android

Tags: android, flutter, google-fit

I'm struggeling to fetch WORKOUTs with the flutter health plugin. I can establish a connection to google fit and I get STEPS but no WORKOUTs.

I tried it with version 6 and 7 of the plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/health/versions/6.0.0, https://pub.dev/packages/health/versions/7.0.1)

I always used the example. In the examples there is also the workout type included and I checked that in the query period there is also a workout. I can see the workouts in Google Fit.

```
static final types = [
HealthDataType.WEIGHT,
HealthDataType.STEPS,
HealthDataType.HEIGHT,
HealthDataType.BLOOD_GLUCOSE,
HealthDataType.WORKOUT,
HealthDataType.BLOOD_PRESSURE_DIASTOLIC,
HealthDataType.BLOOD_PRESSURE_SYSTOLIC,
// Uncomment these lines on iOS - only available on iOS
// HealthDataType.AUDIOGRAM
```

];

```
 List<HealthDataPoint> healthData =
          await health.getHealthDataFromTypes(start, end, types);
```

Anybody has an idea what's the issue?

Comment: Now a copied the whole github sample code with health 8.1 (https://github.com/cph-cachet/flutter-plugins/tree/master/packages/health/example) and I get the same result. I can fetch steps but no workouts. Any idea?